# Webscraping specific information from an API

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the data stored in the value "name" for all items from the following API: https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=128

This API loaded onto the following page: https://smws.com/all-whisky?filter-page=1&per-page=128&sort=pricedesc

Then print out all the values to the terminal. For example:

```
Bonkers for conkers
Its hay season!
The Stuff That Dreams Are Made Of
```

etc...

However for some reason, I can't seem to be able to scrape the information?

Here is my code:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=128")

data = response.json()["data"]

for item in data:
    name = item["name"]
    print(name)
```

Which returns the following error:

```
File "code.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = response.json()["data"]
KeyError: 'data'
```

I can definitely load the entire API using data = response.json(), however can't seem to access specific values for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can access the entire scrape using data = response.json(), however I only need to access the information contained within "name" for each item. Make sense?

Comment: @jsotola no need to be condescending and scrutinize subtle semantics. If he 'could', he wouldn't be asking or receiving an error. People want help, not to be criticized when they've put a good faith effort into asking a question.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I am not being condescending ... precise description is required ... "seem to" is just too unclear ... maybe it has a different meaning in different places

Comment: @jsotola It certainly came across as condescending and at the very least was not helpful. Maybe next time try to be of use to the community instead of nonsensically cringey.

Comment: then, please accept my apology for my remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the `items` object and return the `name` value for each object:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles"

# Define the query parameters
params = {
    "store_id": "uk",
    "parent_id": 61,
    "page": 1,
    "sortBy": "pricedesc",
    "minPrice": 0,
    "maxPrice": 0,
    "perPage": 128,
}

# API request
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

# Parse response
data = response.json()

# Loop through objects and print 'name' values
for item in data["items"]:
    print(item["name"])
```

Output:

```
Bonkers for conkers
It’s hay season!
“The stuff that dreams are made of”
Take a step back in time
SHARING CASE
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can mark correct in 2 minutes!

Is it possible to do this for each URL as well?

Comment: What do you mean by 'each URL'? Are they similar API endpoints? If so, provide an example.

Comment: The variable URL, I figured it out :) Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear. Keep in mind the JSON object structure may differ for each endpoint, so you many need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, sincerely appreciate the help.